# how to retrieve the value of the key from key: value pairs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have following key value pairs in file `object.js`

```
const ObjectUrl = { 
 a: 'www.google.com',
 b: 'www.stackoverflow.com',
}

export default object;
```

I am trying to retrieve the value in anchor tag as follows

```
  import OjbectUrl from './object'
  <Anchor href={ObjectUrl('a')}>
```

When i load the page i get error at line above `Uncaught TypeError: ReactOnRails encountered an error while rendering component: SomeComponent`

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `<Anchor href={ObjectUrl['a']}>`?

Comment: tried that i get lint error: at ['a'] is better written in dot notation

Comment: So then write it with the dot notation: `ObjectUrl.a`.

Comment: `export default ObjectUrl`?

Comment: sweet!! ObjectUrl.a worked. Please add it as answer and i'll makr it as an aswer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Convert

```
<Anchor href={ObjectUrl('a')}>
```

to

```
<Anchor href={ObjectUrl.a}>
```

You mentioned that your linter recommended dot notation for the object. This is because you are referencing the key 'a' all of the time, so there is no need for it to be dynamic. The use case for the non-dot version would be when a variable controlled your key as such:

```
render(){
    const key = 'a' //or any other dynamic value
    return(
        <Anchor href={ObjectUrl[key]}>

        </Anchor>
    )
}
```